# Coin Flipping - Gaps and Islands Problem MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the question: Each member of staff spent the whole day flipping coins, recording the result of each flip. The attached text file shows the combined results of all the coin flips. Find out for each employee what their longest unbroken run of heads was.

```
08:12:16,Gavin,T
08:12:31,Amnon,T
08:12:37,Abe,T
08:12:42,Nandi,T
08:12:49,Gavin,H
08:13:09,Megan,H
08:13:28,Amnon,H
08:13:34,Jessica,H
08:13:35,Henk,H
08:13:52,Claire,H
08:14:04,Gertrude,T
08:14:19,Gavin,T
08:14:32,Megan,H
08:14:35,Amnon,T
08:14:49,Philip,H
08:14:50,Gertrude,T
08:14:59,Henk,T
08:15:05,Steven,T
08:15:24,Gavin,H
08:15:27,Gertrude,T
08:15:41,Megan,H
08:15:46,Kylen,H
08:15:57,Steven,H
08:16:01,Gavin,T
08:16:11,Steven,T
08:16:28,Philip,H
08:16:45,Pierre,T
08:17:07,Amnon,T
08:17:09,Abe,T
08:17:26,Jessica,T
08:17:30,Henk,H
08:17:34,Kylen,H
08:17:54,Andrew,T
08:18:04,Jessica,H
08:18:24,Amnon,H
08:18:30,Vuli,H
08:18:35,Jessica,T
08:18:51,Reut,H
08:18:52,Kylen,T
08:18:53,Gavin,H
08:19:11,Henk,T
08:19:17,Helen,T
08:19:33,Claire,H
08:19:41,Gertrude,T
08:19:42,Illana,H
08:19:55,Amnon,H
08:20:00,Henk,H
08:20:09,Pierre,H
08:20:24,Pierre,H
08:20:36,Maryann,T
08:20:51,Megan,T
08:21:05,Amnon,T
08:21:09,Pierre,T
08:21:28,Reut,T
08:21:41,Illana,T
08:21:53,Gertrude,T
08:21:54,Gavin,H
08:22:08,Vuli,T
08:22:10,Gertrude,T
08:22:12,Henk,T
08:22:25,Amnon,T
08:22:37,Reut,T
08:22:58,Helen,H
08:23:05,Steven,T
08:23:06,Gavin,T
08:23:23,Gertrude,H
08:23:35,Gavin,T
08:23:57,Andrew,H
08:24:00,Claire,H
08:24:03,Reut,H
08:24:22,Abe,T
08:24:32,Helen,H
08:24:35,Andrew,T
08:24:50,Reut,T
08:24:52,Maryann,T
08:25:00,Gertrude,T
08:25:09,Gertrude,T
08:25:29,Steven,H
08:25:47,Gertrude,H
08:26:06,Steven,H
08:26:12,Helen,H
08:26:24,Kylen,T
08:26:44,Megan,T
08:26:56,Jessica,H
08:26:58,Andrew,H
08:27:19,Amnon,T
08:27:24,Pierre,H
08:27:43,Nandi,T
08:28:00,Helen,H
08:28:15,Gertrude,H
08:28:23,Pierre,H
08:28:31,Henk,H
08:28:42,Claire,H
08:28:43,Philip,T
08:28:44,Helen,T
08:29:03,Illana,H
08:29:05,Philip,T
08:29:07,Philip,H
08:29:08,Nandi,H
08:29:24,Nandi,T
```

I recognize this is a Gaps and Islands Problem but i'm running into problems
I reduced the problem to just one user and create a continued sequence of Heads or Tails through this query

```
SELECT time_of_flip, flip_result,
       ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY time_of_flip) AS continues_seq,
       ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition BY flip_result ORDER BY time_of_flip) AS seq_by_value
FROM coin_flipping
where flipper = 'Abe'
order by time_of_flip ASC
```

This is the result

```
08:12:37,T,1,1
08:17:09,T,2,2
08:24:22,T,3,3
08:35:12,H,4,1
08:45:27,H,5,2
08:58:59,H,6,3
08:59:16,T,7,4
09:00:06,H,8,4
09:01:36,H,9,5
09:01:49,T,10,5
09:17:09,T,11,6
09:17:15,T,12,7
09:22:26,H,13,6
09:23:12,H,14,7
09:27:41,T,15,8
09:27:59,T,16,9
09:30:41,T,17,10
09:31:07,H,18,8
09:32:26,T,19,11
09:36:19,H,20,9
09:38:54,H,21,10
09:41:25,H,22,11
09:45:22,T,23,12
09:49:43,T,24,13
09:52:09,T,25,14
09:53:03,H,26,12
09:57:44,H,27,13
10:04:39,T,28,15
10:17:11,H,29,14
10:18:15,T,30,16
```

But i dont know how to proceed to get the result for one staff member and then for all staff members

Answer (score 1):

You can use the difference of row numbers for this.  To get all sequences:

```
SELECT flipper, result, COUNT(*) as num_heads
FROM (SELECT time_of_flip, flip_result,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY flipper ORDER BY time_of_flip) AS continues_seq,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY flipper, flip_result ORDER BY time_of_flip) AS seq_by_value
      FROM coin_flipping
     ) cf
WHERE result = 'H'
GROUP BY flipper, (continues_seq - seq_by_value);
```

The key idea here -- relative to your query -- is to `partition by` the flipper and then aggregate.

Then use an additional subquery to get the max per person:

```
SELECT slipper, MAX(num_heads)
FROM (SELECT flipper, result, COUNT(*) as num_heads
      FROM (SELECT time_of_flip, flip_result,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY flipper ORDER BY time_of_flip) AS continues_seq,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY flipper, flip_result ORDER BY time_of_flip) AS seq_by_value
            FROM coin_flipping
           ) cf
      WHERE result = 'H'
      GROUP BY flipper, (continues_seq - seq_by_value)
     ) f
GROUP BY flipper;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, like a glove!